# How do I get Excel to only print sheets that have been populated with certain data, and exclude the printing of the one sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I am creating a letter generator at work that has one input sheet "Input Info" with 29 rows, each corresponding to 29 sheets with a letter template that pulls data from "Input Info". All letters need to be printed out and mailed but the problem is, we don't always need 30 letters, as some days we only have +-20 we need to print. 
I'm stumped on creating the code that is required to always exclude the data sheet from the print job, and only print the sheets that have pulled data, say H1:H30 from Sheet 1 (Obviously we want the user to print entire workbook, not each individual sheet manually). I'm fairly new to VBA so I've just been doing a lot of searching returning a lot of nothing. Here's some code I have found so far that excludes the first page, yet when I print, the first page still prints.  I just need something I can use now that I can analyze and learn from later as I learn more about VBA on the job. Please help!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean) 
Dim ws As Variant 

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
Application.EnableEvents = False 

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets 
    If ws.Name <> "Input Info" Then 
        ws.PrintOut 
    End If 
Next ws 

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
Application.EnableEvents = True 

Cancel = True 

End Sub
```

Here is a watered-down version of the file.
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=69464232828729057900
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you perhaps share a dumbed down (anonymised) version of your file?

Comment: Yeah sure. Ultimately, I want the printing function to be executed when I hit the "Print" command button I've created on the first sheet. Basically, the sheets that did not pull data from sheet 1, are to get excluded from the print job, as well as the first sheet. That way, end result is: click print button, and if I filled in 15 rows, then those specific 15/29 will only print and not the input sheet. This is the last step before I release to 45 people and it's killing me. I'm sharing the watered down version. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written excludes every sheet whose name is "Input Info" (careful with upper/lower bound letters), so it won't work exactly well.

I didn't test the following but this should help:

```
Sub PrintLetters() 

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim RngCell As Range
Dim NameList As Range

Set NameList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input Info").Range("H1:H30") ' <- This is where you get your data from

For Each RngCell ws In NameList.Cells
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If LCase(ws.Name) = LCase(RngCell.Value) Then ' <- LCase makes sure that you are not CaSe SenSiTIVe
            ws.PrintOut ' or INSERT HERE WHICHEVER CODE TO PRINT ws
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next ws 
Next

End Sub
```

This is a very simple way of going through the content (`.Text`) of each cell you specified (in this case H1:H30 in "Input Info"), and if the name is the same of one of the worksheets of the workbook, then it prints it (more info on `.PrintOut` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff838253.aspx)), otherwise does nothing.

Comment: Replace LBound with LCase and replace .Text with .Value (.Text may yield "####" if a column is too narrow to fit its content)

Comment: XD oops! I was distracted, yes I meant to use `LCase` . About the `.Text`, well you just taught me something new!